# Remove .php extension from just one file to use with Laravel Router

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-routing

I am implementing Laravel Routing component in my own site (https://github.com/mattstauffer/Torch/tree/master/components/routing).

However, most of the site still works on classic url such as /index.php etc. I created new.php file with router and it works, i.e. if I declare get routes for /new.php/test - desired response is displayed.

However, I want to use it like this:
`/new/test`.

How would proper rule look like in .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?new/(.*)/?$ /new.php/$1 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

(".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thanks for an answer. URLs work, however it ignores routing then. If, i.e. in new.php there will be `echo "test";"`, it will echo test on all routes like /new, /new/test, /new/users/5 etc. It won't display anything declared in a specific route. 
For now, it works only with `/new.php` -> route('/') and `/new.php/test` -> route('/test'). Without php extension it all breaks.

Comment: Sorry, I am afraid I do not really understand your comment... Sure, above rules internally rewrite _all_ requests below `/new/` to `/new.php` which should be your routing script, as far as I understood your question. If you now place such `echo` command inside your routeing script, then sure it will execute that for each rewritten command. That is _not_ what you expect? Why not? How should routing work if it is _not_ implemented in that routing script of yours? I have no idea how that routing script you implemented works, so I cannot help there, I am afraid...